# javascript infinite loop error in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

this is the code I am writing atm:

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if ( i > largest) {
    i = largest;
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

It should be alerting the largest number in the array, but it seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: you shouldn't change i!

Comment: never change i in a for loop, and you are not doing anything with the array in the loop

Comment: `largest = i > largest ? i : largest;`

Answer (score 4):

I think you want

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if ( array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
```

Basically you are saying "if `i` is greater than 0, set `i` to 0", which will cause `i` to alternate between 0 and 1 forever.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = arr[0];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if ( arr[i] > largest) {
        largest = arr[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

Comment: It should be `var largest = arr[0]`

Comment: It should be set to `arr[0]`

Comment: well this shouldn't make any difference but you're right. that's better.

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant.

```
var array = [3, 6, 2, 56, 32, 5, 89, 32];
var largest = array[0];

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
    if ( array[i] > largest) {
        largest = array[i];
    }
}

console.log(largest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the value of `i` every time you find a new `largest`, so that you have the infinite loop.  This line makes your loop infinite:

```
i = largest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find max value of array using

```
Math.max.apply(null, array)
```